# Error On Using spl autoload register

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

This is working fine on `init.php`

```
include 'models/m_app.php';
include 'views/v_app.php';
include 'controllers/c_app.php';
```

but the `spl_autoload_register()` is not working

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'models/' . $class . '.class.php';
    include 'views/' . $class . '.class.php';
    include 'controllers/' . $class . '.class.php';
});
```

and I am getting error like

```
Warning: include(models/Model.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\App\core\init.php on line 3
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'models/Model.class.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\App\core\init.php on line 3
Warning: include(views/Model.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\App\core\init.php on line 4
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'views/Model.class.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\App\core\init.php on line 4
Warning: include(controllers/Model.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\App\core\init.php on line 5
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'controllers/Model.class.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\App\core\init.php on line 5
```

Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are using the spl_autoload_register function incorrectly.

An autoload function is getting called, when you are trying to create a class that does not exist.

The correct way would be to name your files just as the class inside them and add an ending like .class.php:

```
View.class.php
Model.class.php
Controller.class.php
```

The autoloader:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    set_include_path('views/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'controllers/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'models/');
    include $class . '.class.php';
});
```

And to test it:

```
$test1 = new Model();
$test2 = new Controller();
$test3 = new View();
```

Comment: Thanks <arc but I really didnt get why the `spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
  require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});` is not working here

Comment: Can you please take a look at this [sample](https://github.com/Erikdekamps/phpacademy/blob/master/core/init.php)   and let me know how come it is working in this example?

Comment: Thats because its gonna look for the file core/classes/... you need to add ../classes/ or /classes ;-)

Comment: As Marc said the function you register to spl autoloader will be invoked when you try to instantiate a class that does not exist. The class name including namespace if exists will be passed to the registered autoload function. This means you have to work with the passed class name and figure out the file + its location + include it by yourself. So far so good. In the code you shared in the first post is at least one mistake. You try to include the file three times from different locations. There is no file exist check either. I recommend to take another look into php.net -> spl_autoload_regist